# Why text file created is blank?

Tags: c++, file-handling

My code is

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <fstream.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct info
{
    char product_name[100], Seller_Name[100], DOP[30];
    int  price;
}data;

void main()
{
    ofstream fout("code.txt",ios::out);
    fout<< "ofstream fout(\"data.dat\",ios::binary|ios::out);\n";
    while(1)
    {
        cout <<  "Enter Product Name: ";
        gets(data.product_name);
        cout<<"Enter Seller Name: ";
        gets(data.Seller_Name);
        cout<<"Enter Date of Purchase: " ;
        gets(data.DOP);
        cout<<"Enter Price:" ;
        cin>>data.price;
        fout<<"strcpy(data.product_name,"<<data.product_name<<");";
        fout<<"nstrcpy(data.Seller_Name,"<<data.Seller_Name<<");";
        fout<<"nstrcpy(data.DOP,"<<data.DOP<<");";
        fout<<"nstrcpy(data.price,"<<data.price<<");";
        fout<<"fout.write((char*)&data,sizeof(info));n";
    }
}
```

I am developing a software and am making sample data for it. So I made this application so I just have to copy statements and need not have to write it again. It worked the first time but now it is not working.

Comment: Is there a problem with your spacebar as the code does not appear to have any indentation

Comment: Why are you mixing `stdio` with `iosteam`?

Comment: **–1** Try posting the **real code**.

Comment: When does the while loop end?

Comment: I think `nstrcpy` -> `\nstrcpy` (and elsewhere). Adding these new lines will also flush the buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your buffer is likely not being flushed.

Try this:

```
while(1){
  //...
  fout.flush();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I used it and it worked... Can you tell me what it is and why I used it?

Comment: @AyushMahajan ofstream is an object.  It's job is to write to the file for you.  However, file I/O is an expensive operation on a machine.  In order to be more efficient, the ofstream object holds in internal buffer.  You can think of this is a temporary array of characters.  It will use this buffer to write to the file all at once.  This is more efficient in the long run. However, if your buffer does not get large enough to flush automatically, or you don't use something like std::endl which flushes for you, you will not see data in the file.

Answer (score 1):

Try closing the output stream when you're done with it

```
fout.close()
```

check out here for more info:
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/

Short:

Data is buffered and only written periodically as an optimization.
Closing the file flushes the buffer (writes everything) and frees up the file for other processes.

Comment: This would indeed work, because closing the file flushes the buffer.

Comment: Yes, closing the file flushes the buffer.

The takeaway is to close files when "done" with them. Done is to be decided by the author.